# How to concat element + data together?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable which stores an element inside it (favIcon) and I extracted the data from inside it(index). Inside the data only integers are stored so I can call it later. My question is how do I concat an element with the data so I can use it to style? Right now I get an error called Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined(favicon). I would like to change the value of the data inside the element if possible. Thanks

```
function favouriteState(){

    var allPlaces = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allPlaces"));
    var favIcon = document.getElementById("favourite");
    var index = favIcon.getAttribute("data");

    console.log(favIcon.index);

    if (allPlaces[index].favourite == true) {
        console.log("It's True");
        favIcon.index.style.color = '#FFE234';
        favIcon.index.querySelector('ion-icon').setAttribute('name', 'star');
    }

    localStorage.setItem("allPlaces", JSON.stringify(allPlaces));
}
```

Comment: "_Cannot read property 'style' of undefined_" means `favicon.index` is `undefined`, just remove `.index`.

Comment: When I remove the .index I don't get the desired result because only one button stays styled the correct way.

Comment: Yes, that's the only you can get when you're getting a single element using `document.getElementById`. If you need more elements, I'd suggest you to group the wanted elements with a class name, and collect them into a list by using `document.querySelectorAll('.classNameOfTheGroup')`. Then you can iterate through the list and handle the collected elements one by one.

Comment: Oh, alright thanks very much. It makes sense what you said.